# Lightbox 2.6 center resized image

Tags: image, resize, center, lightbox, lightbox2

I added to lightbox.css this code

```
img {
max-width: 872px;
max-height: 635px;}.lb-outerContainer, .lb-dataContainer {
max-width: 880px;
width: auto!important;
height: auto!important;}​
```

Is working perfectly to resize the big images, but when I have to open a small image, for example width:267 and height: 200 is showing a white space in the right, and I want to show the image in the center. If the white space can be removed is ok, but if is impossible is no problem, I just want the image to be in center.

Here is a image with the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this code to your css to give your page a height value:

```
body,html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

2. Look up ".lightbox {" in your lightbox.css file and add this rule to make the images fit the height of your webpage:

```
  height: 100%;
```